# Can't Force HTTPS and Non-WWW via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force any regular http request to redirect to https, and also force non www in the URLs, so that every request in the end will be https://example.com

http://example.com becomes https://example.com

http://www.example.com becomes https://example.com

https://www.example.com becomes https://example.com

http://example.com becomes https://example.com

I have the following code in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I am getting an error that states it has too many redirects. It seems to work fine on this test site with the correct output:

[htaaccess tester preview](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Any ideas or a better approach to this?

Comment: @anubhava It shows example.com and says (failed)net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Use command line `curl` to run this command `curl -ILk 'http://example.com'` and post it's output.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

It will redirect everything to https://example.com